# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compare_digest'

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth, django-socialauth

I configured user authorization via `GoogleOauth2.0` (`social-auth-app-django`).

Entries in the *social_django / usersocialauth / application* are not created.

Locally everything works, but an error occurs on the server.

After selecting an account to log in via Google, it redirects to the page

*complete/google-oauth2/ + GET paramteres*

In `Traceback`, I get the following:

**Traceback**

```
ERROR 2019-07-31 19:25:29,351 base 4745 139713585624832 Internal Server Error: /complete/google-oauth2/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/deploy/.virtualenvs/finbee/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/deploy/.virtualenvs/finbee/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/deploy/.virtualenvs/finbee/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
    response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deploy/.virtualenvs/finbee/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deploy/.virtualenvs/finbee/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_django/utils.py", line 49, in wrapper
    return func(request, backend, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deploy/.virtualenvs/finbee/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_django/views.py", line 33, in complete
    *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deploy/.virtualenvs/finbee/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/actions.py", line 43, in do_complete
    user = backend.complete(user=user, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deploy/.virtualenvs/finbee/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/base.py", line 40, in complete
    return self.auth_complete(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deploy/.virtualenvs/finbee/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/utils.py", line 251, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/deploy/.virtualenvs/finbee/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/oauth.py", line 388, in auth_complete
    state = self.validate_state()
  File "/home/deploy/.virtualenvs/finbee/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/backends/oauth.py", line 91, in validate_state
    elif not constant_time_compare(request_state, state):
  File "/home/deploy/.virtualenvs/finbee/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social_core/utils.py", line 227, in constant_time_compare
    return hmac.compare_digest(val1, val2)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'compare_digest'
```

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
            ],

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social_core.pipeline.mail.mail_validation',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social_core.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social_core.pipeline.user.user_details',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #...
    'social_django',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]

SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE = 'social'

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY  =  '***********'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET  =  '****'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/kredity/'
```

**Google**

https://example.com/complete/google-oauth2/

---

social-auth-app-django==3.1.0

social-auth-core==3.2.0

python==2.7.6

Comment: [`hmac.compare_digest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/hmac.html#hmac.compare_digest) was added in 2.7.7 so probably, on the server, you're running an older version.

Comment: 2.7.6 on the server

Comment: How to be in this situation?

Comment: Upgrade your version of Python, if possible. Otherwise, its seems like they recently added this function, see [this commit](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/commit/07c18a81327050334ea71576d397f5d3bb8b0757). Downgrading the package to `3.1.0` would definitely help. In any case I would file an issue at their repo since they didn't seem to update the [`requirements`](https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-core/blob/master/requirements-python2.txt) when introducing this feature, i.e. potentially breaking client code (like yours).

Comment: Thnx. Downgrading the package to `3.1.0` fixed it,